# Can someone explain Green Flame Blade works

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

So this may sound silly, but can someone explain how Green Flame Blade works? How useful is it?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to explain which parts exactly are unclear to you? Currently you are asking "I have this damaging cantrip that can target an enemy I can hit with my sword and a second enemy close to the first one - how do I use it and how is it useful?", which looks to me like it could be answered by restating the spell description that you already gave. By mentioning which parts are causing you trouble we could provide you with an answer geared towards those specific problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally only useful at lower levels. As an example we have two Orcs standing side by side (not more than 5 feet) to each other. We call them Orci and Morci

1. You take an action (*This action casting a spell; a cantrip called "Green-Flame Blade"*)
2. As part of this action "Green-Flame Blade" you make a (only one) melee attack ("Roll d20 + attack bonus+ *Whateveryouhave*) against a foe in your range of the spell (5 feet), I suggest that you want to hit Orci

OPTION A:

3. You hit Orci (make damage, +whatever your attack makes)
4. The magic green fire of the mighty green blade enlightens the poor Orci with incredible hurting flames - flames from hell - and jumps (without hurting Orci) to Morci
5. Morci gets damage in height of your spellcasting modifier
   (6.) At higher Levels you would roll a +dX additionally

OPTION B:

3. You miss Orci
4. Nothing happens

Comment: It burnz uz, Precious!

Comment: I'd also add that it can be extremely useful at higher levels in specific circumstances. For example, it's quite handy for a Rogue/Sorcerer multiclass, since cantrip damage scales with character (not class) level, and Rogues can use Sneak Attack with it.

Comment: @Gandalfmeansme Agreed, the statement about only useful at lower levels is what's preventing my concern with this answer as well as the assumption that the character gets more than one melee attack.

Comment: It's also worth noting that this description is a bit unclear about Option A step 4. If your character is below level 5, the green fire only hurts Morci. At higher levels, it will hurt both Morci and Orci (that is, the +dX, [which would actually be +Xd8] applies to both of them). Only Mmrci will also add your spellcasting modifier to this damage.