# Does the green-flame blade extra damage work on normal attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Can you do a *green-flame blade* cantrip (duration of 1 round), do an Action Surge and then a normal attack action with Extra Attack and have all attacks have the *green-flame blade* bonus damage since it have a duration of 1 round and should also work with opportunity attack in the same round?

Comment: I don't see where you're finding a duration of 1 round. In every source I've seen, its duration is instantaneous. Can you specify where you're finding this?

Comment: FWIW, [this is a related answer to a question about how green flame blade works](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/119261/22566), for background.

Comment: Another Related Question [is here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/114006/if-your-fighter-casts-green-flame-blade-or-booming-blade-do-you-still-get-extra)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## You don't get extra damage on the later attacks

[*Green flame blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/green-flame-blade) doesn't have a duration of 1 round. It is Instantaneous. The spell has you make one attack, which gets extra damage. No other attacks do so.

> As part of the action used to cast this spell, you must make a melee attack with a weapon against one creature within the spell’s range, otherwise the spell fails. On a hit, the target suffers the attack’s normal effects, and [extra damage is applied]

If other attacks would get damage from *green flame blade* it would have a longer duration, as would say something along the lines of

> For the duration of this spell, when you hit with a melee weapon attack a creature within 5 feet of the target takes [...]

You can use Action Surge to get an another attack with extra damage by casting *green flame blade* using the extra action, but you would [only get the attack described by the spell](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/114006/52137).